# Insert data to SQL Azure from android application through Azure Mobile Service

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I have two types of tables under azure Mobile Service: 
Type A : Azure Mobile Service for "Existing Database" (Without creating a new for Mobile Service).
To use existing database , I created a SCHEMA and associated the tables from existing DB to it using following:
CREATE SCHEMA my_new_service;
ALTER SCHEMA my_new_service TRANSFER dbo.Subject;

Type B :  Azure Mobile Service by creating a new table for service.

I created a sample android application to RETRIEVE the table data and works fine in both the cases!
Now when I am trying to insert row into the table in type B table, it gets inserted successfully
But in case of Type A,I get an exception as : com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceException: {"code":400,"error":"Error: Bad request."}
Any Help Appreciated : I have checked for permissions for both the tables and are same.

Answer (score 2):

Solution Please check your Window Azure Log

The Error code  {"code":400,"error":"Error: Bad request."}  will come only when you  not provide the values correctly or the value which is not null constraint is not automatically generating .